# Input type="number" with not mandatory step attribute

Tags: html, input

I have an input in my form with a `step` defined to `3`:

```
<form>
    <input name="surface" id="surface" type="number" step="3" />
</form>
```

I would like to be able to enter a number not multiple of the step, but it's refused at validation by the browser.

In example, if I insert "2.5" in the input, the message error I've got is:

> Please select a valid value. The 2 closest values are 0 and 3.

Is it possible to make this step not mandatory?
I've tried to add `novalidate="novalidate"` as attribute but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why set a step value if you're not going to enforce it?

Comment: @Mr.Llama to have an helper for the users. The field is for a surface, the input value is normally from 9 to more 3 by 3, but users can specify any other surface value, not only a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a bit of javascript:

```
<form>
    <input name="surface" id="surface" type="number" step="3" oninput="allowCustomValue(this)" />
</form>

<script>
function allowCustomValue(input) {
    // Check if the entered value is a multiple of 3
    const value = parseInt(input.value);
    if (value % 3 !== 0) {
        // If not a multiple of 3, remove the step attribute
        input.step = "any";
    } else {
        // If a multiple of 3, set the step attribute back to 3
        input.step = "3";
    }
}
</script>
```

The allowCustomValue function checks if the entered value is a multiple of 3. If it is not, we remove the step attribute temporarily using input.step = "any", which allows users to enter any numeric value. If the entered value is a multiple of 3, we set the step attribute back to 3, enabling the up and down arrows to work in 3 intervals.

Comment: Nice, easy and clean!

Answer (score 2):

After more research, it appears it's not possible to make the step non mandatory on an HTML5 input.

I'll have to implement a custom number input (in jQuery or else) to achieve this.

Comment: Care to share your solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I've implemented anything at the end, and even if I had I don't remember any of it, sorry @MatthiasUrlichs